# SignalR - ChatHub Dependency Management for Database Operation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, signalr, autofac

**Background:**

I have a web application in which I have SignalR as well.
I'm using AutoFac as DI container where my database is registered as
`builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().AsSelf().InstancePerLifetimeScope();`

i.e. MyDbContext is registered as PerRequestDependency.

The ChatHub is also registered with same dependency level. i.e.

```
builder.Register<IHubContext>((c) =>
{
    return GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<ChatHub>();
})
.InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

**Problem:**
The problem I am facing is - The DbContext throws error saying there are multiple threads calling the DbContext.
Here is the exact error:

> `System.NotSupportedException`: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe. at `System.Data.Entity.Internal.ThrowingMonitor.EnsureNotEntered()`

**Note:** I have looked into entire code and I am 100% sure that I have awaited all async calls to the database.

**Possible Solution:**
If I change the AutoFac registration to per below then the error goes away but I feel, it will require more database connections.
`builder.RegisterType<MyDbContext>().AsSelf();`
i.e. remove InstancePerLifetimeScope

**Expectation:**
Better solution than increasing database connections.

Comment: show the section of code where this exception occured

Comment: @EhsanSajjad - It occurs at multiple places and does not occur at the same line everytime.

Comment: try to find similar error , as I remember it is frequent problem

Comment: I don't know AutoFac, but for the IServiceCollection in .Net Core you have to wrap your context inside an IServiceScopeFactory because the SignalR hub is a singleton and your context is scoped.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't open the same entity twice.

Example:

```
var x = db.user.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.id == 1);
.
some code here
.
var y = db.user.FirstOrDefault(a=>a.id == 1);

y.userName = "";
```

Comment: I doubt this can be a problem.